# Font Awesome not working within Router Link Vue.js (Possible Vue-Router Bug)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, font-awesome, vue-router

## The Issue

For some reason, when I place a Font Awesome icon as the first child of a `router-link`, Vue decides to ignore anything after the icon (the icon itself works).

See the following:

```
<router-link to="/"><font-awesome-icon icon="book" />Documentation</router-link>
```

This outputs:

```
// Actual: 
<a...><svg>...<svg></a>

// Expected:
<a...><svg>...<svg>Documentation</a>
```

Has anyone else experienced this? Am I doing something wrong?

## What I have Tried

I have tried wrapping the icon and text in a `span` tag like so:

```
<router-link to="/"><span><font-awesome-icon icon="book" />Documentation</span></router-link>
```

This yields the same result as above (plus the span tags)...

I also tried placing the icon on the other side (just for testing), and this worked!

```
<router-link to="/">Documentation<font-awesome-icon icon="book" /></router-link>
```

The above test worked, however, it is obviously not what I want and I am not overly keen on just repositioning the icon with CSS (very dirty fix)

## My Assumption

I believe this may actually be a bug with vue-router when rendering empty elements but I cannot be sure. I guess I could test with a `<br />` tag and see what happens... I shall be back!

Update: I can confirm that empty elements **do** work! I just tried the following and it worked fine:

```
<router-link to="/"><br />Documentation</router-link>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I only asked it 25 mins ago... :-) - That's a no, not yet

Comment: found one, typing it

Comment: @Mohd_PH are you having the same issue? I am only playing around with Vue so I am not bothered, but thought I would ask the question in case anyone else runs into it...

Comment: @Mohd_PH What I am hoping for is someone to tell me I am doing it wrong, or it is a bug. I am not actually that interested in finding a way around it because I could probably do this pretty easily... It's more about whether this is the right way to do this :-)

Comment: I copied the code from library docs but didn't work so I think it is a bug, it worked when I bounded an icon to it, see the example I don't know how to explain :D

Answer (score 2):

It worked with me when I imported the icon then bind it `:icon` , you can see the example [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lll9l31117) , or below :

```
<template>
 <div class="hello">
    <router-link to="/"><font-awesome-icon :icon="icon" />Documentation</router-link>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
 import faBook from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faBook'
 export default {
  name: 'hello',
  components:{
    'font-awesome-icon' : FontAwesomeIcon 
  },
  computed:{
    icon(){
        return faBook;
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hmmmm... Does it work if you do it the same way as me? i.e. are you able to replicate my issue? Assuming I will have numerous icons on any given page, having to compute each one is really poor code... Not to mention, this would only needed to be done when the icon is within a `router-link`, thus promoting inconsistency in the code design. Essentially it is just a workaround...

Comment: Which confirms what I suspected, it is a bug :-)

Comment: No it did not work, same as you. even outside `router-link` .  [here is an example](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#using-it-with-vue) in the docs

Comment: You need to import the specific icon into the template before it will work in the way I have done it, as illustrated in the docs. The `compute` method is *not* a requirement, hence it works when the icon is not the first child. I will give you an upvote for your effort and time as it is very much appreciated, but I won't accept this as the answer as it is just a workaround to achieve what I need. I hope that is okay with you - I just want to keep this open for others as they may find something wrong with the code I have written, or confirm that it is a bug

Comment: Cheers mate, have a great one :-D